# How to write the code of a function outside the class? c++

Tags: c++, function, class, oop, object

I am new in c++ and i am learning classes and objects. In the class I have defined a function, and I want to write the code of it out od the class.
I think it shoud be something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class student{
    public:
        string name;
        int mark1, mark2;

        float calc_media(int, int);

        void disp(){
            cout << "Student:" << name << endl;
            cout << "Media:"<< calc_media(int, int) << endl;
        }


};

student::float calc_media(int x, int y){
    float media = (x + y)/2.0; 

    return media; 
}


int main (){
    student peter;

    cout <<"name:" ;
    cin>>peter.name;
    cout <<"mark1:" ;
    cin>>peter.mark1;
    cout <<"mark2:" ;
    cin>>peter.mark2;
    cout <<"media:" << peter.calc_media(peter.mark1, peter.mark2) << endl << endl;

    peter.disp();

    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone help me because it doesn't work. It shows these errors:
`expected primary expression before 'int'` in the line 13 and `expected unqualified-id before 'float'` in the line 19.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return_type class_name::member_function_name(parameters)
{
   //action
}
```

In Your Case:

```
float student::calc_media(int x, int y)
{
    float media = (x + y)/2.0; 
    return media; 
}
```

In your class change this

```
  cout << "Media:"<< calc_media(int, int) << endl;
```

To

```
  cout << "Media:"<< calc_media(mark1, mark2) << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two simple typos in your example.

`cout << "Media:"<< calc_media(int, int) << endl;`

You must pass two values here not a type. So you could write

`cout << "Media:"<< calc_media(2, 2) << endl;`

This is the reason why you compiler reject this program.
Beside of this there is another typo in your code that will encounter after fixing the first:

```
student::float calc_media(int x, int y){
   float media = (x + y)/2.0; 
   return media; 
}
```

This is also a typo it must be

```
float student::calc_media(int x, int y){
    float media = (x + y)/2.0; 
    return media; 
}
```